# useGLTF taking too much time on first time loading

Tags: reactjs, next.js, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I am currently using `useGLTF` from `@react-three/drei` to load my 3d model. I have already compressed the model using `gltf-pipeline` (the .glb file is 1.7MB). However, for the first time accessing the website, the model takes a extremely long time to load (about 30-50 seconds). You can check out my code below:

```
import { Canvas, useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { useGLTF, Environment, OrbitControls } from '@react-three/drei'
import React, { Suspense, useRef } from 'react'
import styles from './ThreeScene.module.css'

function Robot(props) {
    const { scene } = useGLTF('/compressed-robot.glb');
    return <primitive object={scene} {...props} />;
}

export default function Model() {
    const ref = useRef();
    return (
        <div className={styles.canvas}>
            <Suspense fallback={<div className="center">loading</div>}>
                <Canvas shadows dpr={[1, 2]} camera={{ position: [3, 3, 3], fov: 50 }}>
                    <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
                    <Robot position={[0, -0.9, 0]} scale={0.7} />
                    <Environment preset="city" />
                    <OrbitControls ref={ref} autoRotate enableZoom={false} enableRotate={true} autoRotateSpeed={4.0} />
                </Canvas>
            </Suspense>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Any ideas how I can improve the performance? I am using `NextJS`.

I have tried searching for solutions, but those founded were all for `@react-three`. I am using a basic model here, so I used the pre-built function `useGLTF()` from `@react-three/drei`. And I could not find a solution for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm more in THREE.js than react three fiber but...

Do you have the polygon Count on youre model ?

I had a problem like that before loader some models...my polygons count was to high...

Try this page and lower the polygons count with blender to see if it can helps.

[reduce polygon count](https://help.augment.com/en/articles/2666702-blender-2-7-how-to-reduce-the-polygons-count)

Have a great day !